# Command-line virus scanner on W2k3

Tags: command-line-interface, scripting, anti-virus

Hey all, I wrote a PoSH script that searches an FTP site and downloads specific zip files. In the process, I use AVG-free to run a scan on the zip files, before and after they are decompressed.

Now I am ready to put this sucker into production, on an assigned Windows 2003 Std server. The problem is AVG-free does not support this OS and won't install. Are there any other command-line AV tools out there? The current solution that my company uses (Symantec AV) does not support command-line usage. I want to avoid having an active "AV shield" which will simply monitor a working folder. I want instant results and return codes, which I use to generate alert e-mails.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClamAV has a port that works on Windows. It's an open-source on-demand scanner, made to be scripted (it's meant for plugging into things like UNIX mail servers so it can be easily called from a script to scan incoming and outgoing files). It may fit your needs perfectly here.

Comment: Its no longer supported or updated however.

Comment: What? When did that happen?? I'll have to check the links...(we decommissioned the Linux mail filter we were using awhile back, but Clam was a prominent contender for AV for that specific purpose...)

Comment: The software works however -- and can use the new virus def's.

Comment: There are apparently other efforts for Win32 (or run under cygwin). See: http://wiki.clamav.net/bin/view/Main/ClamUnofficialWindows

Comment: Thanks guys. I got the port (ClamWin) and it seems to be working great. I just need to get the return codes implement it into my PoSH script. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[**NOD32**](http://www.eset.com/) is an excellent scanner and has [**command-line options**](http://www.eset.com.tw/support/commandline.htm).  Not free, though...

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to try scripting your needs in Linux then [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/) would be a great choice...  You could setup a Linux VM to run the task.

Answer (score 1):

**[ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/)?  [FPROT?](http://support.f-prot.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=197&group=en&languageid=1)**

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer McAfee - they have a command line scanning utility - but you may need to buy a minimum number of Enterprise licenses (10 at most, I expect) to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Metascan is available with up to 8 built in antivirus engines, or simply as as core service/api to integrate your own separately licensed antivirus application. Check it out...
http://www.opswat.com/products/metascan